# Style list with icons using jquery UI

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an unsorted list. I want each list item to display one or more icons in a row, and some plain text. I've tried the HTML below (using jquery UI), but the icons are displayed one below the other, not in a row.

```
<ul class="ui-widget">
  <li class="ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-comment"></span>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-suitcase"></span>
    <span>Mr Kevin</span>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-contact"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong ?

Comment: Use Firebug to figure out what part of the "ui-corner-all" rule is making the layout the way you see it. It should take like 10 seconds to do; just disable the rules one by one until the content looks like inline content.  (First scan for a "white-space: pre" rule of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I just did what I said to do in my comment. :-)  The icons themselves are styled by jQuery UI CSS to be "display: block".

You can add a class to your `<li>`:

```
<li class="ui-corner-all ui-state-default my-list-item">
```

then a CSS rule of your own:

```
li.my-list-item .ui-icon { display: inline-block; }
```

For older IE versions that don't support "inline-block", just give them a "zoom: 1" and "inline" style, and that should make them work (I think; you might have to fiddle with it).